# Converting JSON array of [object, Object], [object, Object] to actual values?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have this in my controller:

```
  def selectmodels
    @brand = Brand.find_by_name(params[:brand_name])
    @models = Model.where(:brand_id => @brand.id)
    render json: @models
  end
```

The returned code is processed by:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/selectmodels?brand_name=' + test, type: 'get', 
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "record_not_found") {
            alert("Record not found");
        }
        else {
            alert(data);
            $('#style_model_name').autocomplete({ source: data });
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to have the "data" keys and values loaded up into my autocomplete text-field.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I receive the following:

```
[{"brand_id":1,"created_at":"2012-04-09T03:12:43Z","id":1,"name":"x","updated_at":"2012-04-09T03:12:43Z"},{"brand_id":1,"created_at":"2012-04-09T03:15:54Z","id":2,"name":"y","updated_at":"2012-04-09T03:15:54Z"},{"brand_id":1,"created_at":"2012-04-09T09:33:59Z","id":5,"name":"z","updated_at":"2012-04-09T09:33:59Z"}]
```

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: Well, the alert(data) causes an alert pop-up which just says "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" ... When I use the text-field  the autocomplete is working because when I type 3 blank fields turn up.. but no words inside them. Thanks!

Comment: ..and actually, I don't think I need the keys to load into the autocomplete.. just the text values.

Comment: What do you receive exactly? You can use chrome network console (for example) to monitor network requests/responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/selectmodels?brand_name=' + test, type: 'get', 
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "record_not_found") {
            alert("Record not found");
        }
        else {
            var source = [];
            for (i in data) {
                for (k in data[i]) {
                    source.push(data[i][k]);
                }
            }
            $('#style_model_name').autocomplete({ source: source });
        }
    }
});
```

Or if you only want certain fields:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/selectmodels?brand_name=' + test, type: 'get', 
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "record_not_found") {
            alert("Record not found");
        }
        else {
            var source = [];
            for (i in data) {
                source.push(data[i]['name']);
                source.push(data[i]['id']);
                source.push(data[i]['brand_id']);
            }
            $('#style_model_name').autocomplete({ source: source });
        }
    }
});
```